# Are converted airliners fitted with key-operated locks/switches for security?

Tags: security

Light aircraft are commonly fitted with key-operated doors (cabin, cargo compartments) and key-operated switches (magneto/starter) in a manner very similar to most road vehicles. Airliners are not fitted with any such key-operated door latches or essential switches. The difference is due to the security environments in which they are operated/stored. A light aircraft such as a Cessna 172 might be parked in an unmonitored location readily accessible to almost anyone. Airliners are practically never left unattended and unmonitored. But what happens when an airliner is sold out of commercial service and refitted as a private jet? Would such an aircraft still be attended or monitored full time? Do they get fitted with security devices such as key locks on the doors and/or some sort of key operated interlock to deter unauthorized entry or engine starts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do large commercial aircraft have keys?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/60415/do-large-commercial-aircraft-have-keys)

Comment: @RonBeyer I don't think this is a duplicate. The OP seems to already know about the fact that airliners don't have keys. The question is specifically about the conversion to a private jet.

Comment: @RonBeyer I already know about security approaches for airliners used in commercial service. My question is about aircraft converted from commercial to private use and whether this puts them in a security environment more like that of privately owned light aircraft and are therefore fitted with similar security devices (keys) as part of the conversion.

Comment: Voting to close as opinion based.  Implementing security measures would be the sole responsibility of the new owner, and there is no concise answer that might accurately capture any and all location factors, and/or decisions that might be made.